# C# WinForms: What happens to the UI control resource when I open a new modal window with ShowDialog() and close it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

If I open a new modal form with `ShowDialog()` and close it, the resource is not released, and is it still there?
I am having a cross-thread problem when accessing the modal form's `ListBox` after closing the modal form.
`listbox.Items.Add()` works without problems, but the above problem only occurs when `listbox.Items.Clear()` is used.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code, please? Don't you forget to put `Invoke`?

Comment: When you `ShowDialog()` a new Form instance, do it with a `using` statement (`using (myForm f = new myForm() { [...] f.ShowDialog(); var someValue = f.SomePublicProperty [...] }` ). Unmanaged resources you create (e.g., Graphics objects) need to be disposed of explicitly. It's not clear how you're accessing a ListBox, since controls are usually `private` (for very good reasons). It's also not clear how threading is involved here. You need to post all the details that can describe your context and operations.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko [Link to test code Git repository](https://github.com/ojiwoong/test) Invoke was used.  
The order in which the exceptions are thrown.  
1. Click the Form button to proceed to the Form2 Showdialog.  
2. Click the Close button to close Form2
3. After a few seconds, clicking the button of the Form1 causes a cross-thread exception.  
I want to keep the Form2 object created and open and close it.
Should I use Show and Hide?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class derived from `ApplicationContext`. In there you can have as many forms as you like, add and remove forms etc. When forms close reduce it's form count - when 0, call `ExitThread();`. In program.cs, instead of calling `Application.Run(new YourForm());` pass an instance of your custom context.